# How to install sbt ensime plugin globally?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, zsh, ensime

I've created **~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt**

After that **cd** into **~/.sbt/1.0/plugins**

I've run **addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "2.5.1")**

But I had this error **zsh: unknown sort specifier**

Any Ideas?

Comment: `addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "2.5.1")` is not a command to run. It has to be written in the `plugins.sbt` file you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From sbt documentation. You should create a build.sbt (`~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/build.sbt`) file with that line:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "2.5.1")
```

You don't need to run this command.

Here is a link to documentation where you can see it:

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Plugins.html#Global+plugins

> You can create ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins//build.sbt and put addSbtPlugin() expressions in there to add plugins to all your projects at once. Because doing so would increase the dependency on the machine environment, this feature should be used sparingly.

Comment: This is correct, but it does not have to be named "build.sbt", anything with the file extension ".sbt" is automatically included in every build.